# Saving LESS file that start with underscore does not generate css in Web Essentials 2013

Tags: css, visual-studio-2013, less, web-essentials

I'm using Web Essentials 2013 Update 4 in visual Studio 2013, and normally I can create a file with .less extension and saving it produces the .css as expected. However, if the filename starts with an underscore e.g. "_Layout.less" then no .css is produced (although the compiled form is shown in the preview window).

Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that is by design, from [here](https://webessentials.uservoice.com/forums/140520-general/suggestions/3319359-don-t-compile-nested-less-files):

> I break out my LESS files into different nested files and import them
>   all. As they are nested, there's no need to compile them when changed.
>   I'd love to have the ability to flag a file to not be compiled,
>   similar to how you can flag a CSS file to be minimized.
>
> A convention-based approach used by SASS is to prefix the file with an
>   underscore, so _sub.scss wouldn't be compiled and main.scss would.
>   While not a LESS convention (I don't think there is one), this would
>   be an awesome convention to adopt.

Comment: Without an explanation on SO, your answer is not as good as it could be.